# Deserialize XML to derived objects from base class c#

Tags: c#, xml, abstract-class, xml-deserialization

I want to deserialize XML to derived objects (using base class):

First XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <root>
    <elementOne>101</elementOne>
    <elementTwo>10</elementTwo>
  </root>
```

Second XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <root>
    <elementOne>101</elementOne>
    <elementTwo>10</elementTwo>
    <elementThree>10</elementThree>
  </root>
```

I have following base class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class ResponseBase
{
}
```

Following derived classes:

```
public class DerivedOneClass: ResponseBase
{
  [XmlElementAttribute("elementOne")]
  public string ElementOne {get; set;}
  [XmlElementAttribute("elementTwo")]
  public string ElementTwo {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedTwoClass: ResponseBase
{
  [XmlElementAttribute("elementOne")]
  public string ElementOne {get; set;}
  [XmlElementAttribute("elementTwo")]
  public string ElementTwo {get; set;}
  [XmlElementAttribute("elementThree")]
  public string ElementThree {get; set;}
}
```

But unable to deserialize using base class, following is the code:

```
(T)(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you get a specific error message?

Comment: Without supplying explicit type information, no serializer is going to assume what type you want just based on matching property names.

Comment: At this time I receive ResponseBase class, I want it to return DerivedOneClass or DerivedTwoClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let the serializer know about the derived classes.
You have two options for that:

**Attributes**

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedOneClass))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedTwoClass))]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class ResponseBase
{
}
```

**Pass it directly**

```
(T)(new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), 
      new[]{typeof(DerivedOneClass),typeof(DerivedTwoClass)}
)).Deserialize(reader);
```

When serializing the data, the `XmlSerializer` will automatically add a `xsi:Type` attribute to each item. In your example, the serializer can't know which of the two classes you want to deserialize, so if you are not the one generating the XML, you might need to manually parse the XML with an `XmlDocument` or something similar.

Another way (if you want to keep the `XmlSerializer`) would be to manually determine the type before parsing it.

```
private static void AddTypeDefinition(XmlDocument document)
{
    const string xsiNamespaceUri = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

    XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("root");
    if (node == null) return;

    string type = "DerivedOneClass";

    XmlNodeList nodes = node.SelectNodes("//elementThree");
    if(nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0)
        type = "DerivedTwoClass";

    var typeAttribute = node.Attributes["type", xsiNamespaceUri];
    if (typeAttribute != null) continue;

    XmlAttribute attribute = document.CreateAttribute("xsi", "type", xsiNamespaceUri);
    attribute.Value = type;
    node.Attributes.Append(attribute);
}
```

Can be used like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseBase));
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(stream);

AddTypeDefinition(document);

XmlReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(originalDocument);
ResponseBase result = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as ResponseBase;
```

[Proof of concept on dotNetFiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/QboOnp)

Comment: I used XmlInclude attribute, but deserializer is returning a ResponseBase object

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that. Could you rephrase that?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani And why wouldn't it? As mentioned above, without the `xsi:type` attribute it doesn't know any better. Try serializing data with this method and you should be able to deserialize it as `DerivedOneClass` and `DerivedTwoClass`. The way your XML looks now, you'll have to manually parse or upgrade the xml (I'll post some more code on how to do that shortly).

Comment: Yes I am manually doing it right now, but wanted to know if there is a way deserialzer could do it for me.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I've added some example code on dotNetFiddle to illustrate how to use the XmlSerializer after manually determining the data type.

Comment: Thanks, I saw it on fiddle, will have to do some work on my XMLs as actual xml contains more elements, but you gave me head start. Thanks (y)